# Is it possible to setup a git repo so one branch can never be merged directly into another branch?

Tags: git

If I say have a `test` branch that I never want to be merged into `staging`, would that be possible to set up? I.e. if I have `feature-branch-a` and that is merged into `test` it would not be possible to merge in `test -> staging`, but `feature-branch-a -> staging` would work fine.

Comment: How would you know where a commit comes from?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Locally, you can do it with a pre-commit hook, as described in "[Is there a way to keep two branches from merging in git](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4061152/6309)".
But that hook won't replicate amongs repos, it will stay local.

If you have a centralized repo server, you can add [gitolite](http://sitaramc.github.com/gitolite/master-toc.html) and declare a similar hook as a [VREF (update hook)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10888358/6309).

Comment: gitolite is not a prerequisite for using an update hook to reject a push - heh you've updated the linked answer since I last read it =)