# Handle a same codebase, different app versions in git

Tags: android, git, code-reuse, codebase

I developed a **general application**, because I need to create some very similar app. I tried to **separate the differences**, so I have a **settings.xml**. But it’s not enough because sometimes I need to change the **code** in a version, but I really want to have a same codebase for every app.

I want to reach my main goal, so if I develop the same codebase, then **all app version is upgraded**.
But I have difficulties to **handle the differences**.

I need your suggestions, how should I handle this in **git**.
Should I create a **brach for every app version**? How should I handle the different things *(app name, icon, package name, settings.xml, maybe different code parts)* and still be able to develop the same codebase and upgrade every app version.

Maybe a buildserver script can handle some file replace, but it can't handle the different code versions.

Is there someone with the same problem? Maybe a working solution?

Answer (score 1):

For a common code base, with few different files, one app per branch is the recommended approach (much simpler than [submodules](http://git-scm.com/book/en/Git-Tools-Submodules)).

You can see an example at "[Multiple Django sites with shared codebase and DB](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11803686/6309)".

The problem with this approach is to prevent any merge from the `app` branch to `master` (you should only merge from `master` to `app`).
A [`pre-commit` hook can help](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4061152/6309).
And you [can protect your specific files with a `.gitattributes`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3970442/6309) in the `app` branch.

Comment: @user2313423 any good experience with `git submodules` or did you find something else that worked better meanwhile?